# Raspberry pi 0's GPIO not working (no output)

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio

So I used to use a Raspberry Pi 3B to control my LED strip. It was, of course, an overkill but a fun project.
I now want to do the same but with a Raspberry Pi Zero w. I got one, soldered the GPIO header and tried. The code controlling them works, but no led are turning on. I tried to put the SD card from the RPi 0 to the RPi 3 without any changes and plugged everything the same, and it works, so I have no idea where the problem is. In my knowledge, there are no differences between the RPi 0 and RPi 3 GPIOs. My soldering is not perfect, could the problem come from there?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Imperfect soldering could result in an open circuit, but that seems unlikely.  More likely is that two or more pins are shorted due to a solder bridge.  If so, whether that killed your Pi, killed a couple of pins, or did no damage depends on which pins were shorted.  So, inspect the soldering job carefully, and is pins are shorted, please let us know which ones.

Comment: I think there is a solder bridge between the pins 15 and 17, but as I'm not using them, I reckoned it wouldn't be a problem. I tried to check if my pins were working with gpiotest and it says none of the GPIO is failing, this utility should detect if pins are shorted right ? Also, I did not solder all of the pins, most of them + the one I need. Would it be a problem ?

Comment: Someone who knows more than I will need to comment on that.  If you have a multi-meter, check 5V to GND and 3.3V to GND.  No meter?  Try an LED with series resistor.  (You can remove that solder bridge with solder wick, and you probably should do that even if it's not causing an immediate problem.)